# SSH Tunnel through Android device

Tags: ssh, wifi-tethering

My friend has a little trouble getting around his new Linux system. I'm fairly knowledgeable in that topic so I want to SSH into his machine to take a look for myself.

Problem is he lives in a student hall, so he can't simply forward a port in the router. My idea was to create a Android WifiHotspot, connect his computer and forward port 22 to his local address. I tried that at home but none of the apps really work or want to do what I want (I don't want to SSH into my phone, I want to forward a port in my phone to a computer) and the questions asked to the topic are mostly 'opening ports for games' or 'SSH into my phone from my computer' but not really what I want. 
There us the app 'Port Forwarder' that seems to do what I want but it didn't really work.
On the flip side, I couldn't even ping my phone, so there might be something more wrong.

Can someone help?

Comment: Answered here: [How to port-forward internet using Android Hotspot to PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/218526). Related: [How to connect to Android through SSH over 3G/4G public IP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526)

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are in the same network as your friend, you may just connect
2. if you are in a different network and you want to connect to the computer through your android phone, you probably have to forward the port from your mobile Internet access to the machine, I think this is **not possible**
3. you have to use a vpn to your private network and put those two virtual networks together (your vpn and your LAN) then you might connect your friends pc to that vpn and access it as it would be in the same network as you. **recommended** but maybe not easy because you have to set up a vpn server on your local machine and make your friend connect.
4. if you have to use the android access point, you will have to connect the android to that vpn and route your friends traffic through the vpn, **not easy** and also requires changes on your friends machine