# Port to port routing in rooted android device locally

Tags: root-access, ssh, firewall, termux, voip

I want to route the incoming TCP packets of one specific IP.
Packet can arrive on any port on android. Packet needs to be forwarded to one specific port on the same device, Without using middleware server (router etc) .
Can SSH server or firewall be used? Or is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Solutions suggested here should work for on-device forwarding as well: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/218526