# is it possible to use a mobile phone internet access as a hot spot to a PC and PORT FORWARD for TELNET access to BBS running on laptop?

Tags: settings, connection-issues, mobile-data, android-pc

I have set up a BBS on my laptop and use my mobile data for all internet access.
I am able to connect to other BBS's via TELNET so assume port 23 is open on mobile network, EE.
I assume my phone is acting as the router and can get its IP from cmd: ipconfig listed as default gatway.
also setup dynamic IP via NOIP with a host name pointing to the laptop IP found on the noip system
BUT no one is able to connect to 'myhostname.ddns.net:23?
firewall is configured to open port 23.
I am thinking is because I am using mobile data for internet access and port 23 is not open for inbound traffic on the mobile network. yet i did read in another post that EE dont block any ports.
Does anyone know how I can enable connections to my BBS over the mobile network? even if it involves some android app on my phone to open the port
phone is Galaxy A20e
Android 11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to port-forward internet using Android Hotspot to PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168422/how-to-port-forward-internet-using-android-hotspot-to-pc)

Comment: its half answers it, as it gives the reason no one can connect to the BBS while i use mobile hot spot as internet access, BUT it looks like it can be done via an app, such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elixsr.portforwarder&gl=GB

Comment: I suggest rereading my answer. It already mentions the app you linked. The app does just port forwarding which my answer explains in very detail. "*no one can connect to the BBS*" (from internet) is due to the fact that your mobile data network is behind CGNAT put by your carrier. That's a different issue explained in the [other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526) linked in the above linked answer.

Comment: Solved. Thank you,

Comment: Solved. Thank you, What was confusing is there is a video about the App, that implies that the App port forwards, then goes on to say that the gateway IP needs to be public. because of this I thought i could apply for a public IP from my service provider, so thought it would be possible. After doing some reading I see that it is not that at the moment, not possible, due to CGNAT on IPv4, BUT all being well in the future when (if) mobile service providers move to IPv6 it may be. thaknk you for you reply.