# Android 13 ethernet tethering forward all ports

Tags: networking, tethering, android-13, ethernet

i want to forward the mobile Internet on my rooted Pixel 7 to my router. My router forwards ports 80/443 to a client in my local network to host some web services. I want to be able to forward the ports from my phone to the local client:

**Internet** --5G (rmnet1)--> **Pixel 7** --Ethernet (eth0)--> **Router** --> **Client**:443

I have no GCNat in front of the Pixel 7. In fact i can forward non priviliged ports with the [Fwd: port forwarder app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elixsr.portforwarder&hl=en&gl=US) and its working as expected

Ideally all ports would be forwarded to the router as i also want to use Wireguard. I would also be happy if the phone is only working as a dumb modem, bridging the two interfaces.

I already tried the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/a/431607/439478) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/384670), but requests always timed out.

Comment: As stated in the question I have no GCNAT. I have a public ipv4 which I can call. I can even forward non privileged ports via the fwd app.